# What are incoming and outgoing properties in Freebase?

Tags: semantic-web, freebase, mql

What are incoming and outgoing properties in Freebase? I know about properties for a given type in a given domain, but I also see incoming and outgoing properties associated with a property. I tried to find documentation for this  but couldn't find anything substantial. Does anyone know what these are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you provided an example or context to help clarify your question.  Properties can be a master or not, which is a little like incoming/outgoing, but I suspect you are actually asking about incoming/outgoing **links** not properties.

As Philip said, a property is just a typed object in the graph, so the outgoing links have the values for the `/type/property` properties - expected type (similar to rdf range), uniqueness, what type it belongs to, etc.  Incoming links have the given property as it's value or object.  For properties, this is often another property as the subject/source, "delegating" to this property (ie reusing this property with a different name in a different type).

Outgoing Links

```
property    target  expected type
/type/object/type   /type/property
/type/property/schema   /people/person
/type/property/expected_type    /type/datetime
/type/property/unique   true /type/boolean
```

Incoming Links

```
source  property
/m/0dl8xrg birthDate    /type/property/delegated
```

If we go and look at [the source](http://www.freebase.com/inspect/m/0dl8xrg) of that incoming link we see that it's the property `/base/svocab/person/birthdate` which has the corresponding outgoing link delegating to `/people/person/date_of_birth`

The direction of a link is aligned with the semantics it has, but links can be navigated in either direction.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Tom. If you visit this page: http://www.freebase.com/schema/type/property, you shall see that there is a section called "Incoming Properties", which I believe is different from incoming links. I referred to this and wanted to know what these incoming properties are?

Comment: The context helps a lot.  In that context, it means "properties for which this type (/type/property) is the expected type."  So, for example, all /type/type/properties are of type /type/property.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Actually I could understand this in the schema of a /people/person type. What I typed as a link made it slightly confusing. Now clear :)

Answer (score 2):

The Freebase schema (ie the types and properties) is stored in the same graph as the the rest of the data - as such, in the same way as a topic (eg `/m/05mw61p`) has a `/type/object/name` property ("Stack Overflow" in that case), a property is just another node in the graph and has its own `/type/object/name` property - so the `/type/object/name` property of `/people/person/date_of_birth` will point to "Date of birth".

Again as with everything else, properties have their own schema which defines the things which make them a property rather than just another node - some of these properties are pretty obvious as to what they are (eg `/type/property/expected_type`), but some of the others are a bit obscure and pretty badly documented.